# shared preference concept login page from server validation in android

Tags: java, android

i am validation of login page is done by server side.i create one checkbox for remember username and password.if check box is checked it remembers the username and password.But the problem is even if check box unchecked also it finds stored username and password. now i want if checkbox is unchecked means it cannot remember username and password

```
 i try this code
   public class Login extends Activity {
  SharedPreferences app_preferences ;
CheckBox check;


private static final String UPDATE_URL = "serverurl";

public ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private EditText UserEditText;

private EditText PassEditText;



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");

    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);



    UserEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);

    PassEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    check=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    String Str_user = app_preferences.getString("username","0" );
    String Str_pass = app_preferences.getString("password", "0");
    String Str_check = app_preferences.getString("checked", "no");
    if(Str_check.equals("yes"))
    {
            UserEditText.setText(Str_user);
           PassEditText.setText(Str_pass);
            check.setChecked(true);
    }
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okbutton);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            int usersize = UserEditText.getText().length();

            int passsize = PassEditText.getText().length();

            if(usersize > 0 && passsize > 0) {

                progressDialog.show();

                String user = UserEditText.getText().toString();

                String pass = PassEditText.getText().toString();
                String Str_check2 = app_preferences.getString("checked", "no");
                if(Str_check2.equals("yes"))
                {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("username", user);
                    editor.putString("password", pass);
                     editor.commit();
                }

                doLogin(user, pass);

            } else createDialog("Error","Please enter Username and Password");

        }

    });

   check box
    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                {

                     editor.putString("checked", "yes");
                     editor.commit();
                }
                else
                {
                     editor.putString("checked", "no");
                     editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: How many times you will ask same question again & again....???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 String Str_check = app_preferences.getString("checked", "no");
    if(Str_check.equals("yes"))
    {
String Str_user = app_preferences.getString("username","0" );
    String Str_pass = app_preferences.getString("password", "0");

            UserEditText.setText(Str_user);
           PassEditText.setText(Str_pass);
            check.setChecked(true);
    }
else{
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("username", "");
                    editor.putString("password", "");
                     editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: i try this nothing can happen. i got same out put.if check box is checked means it remember username and password or else it does not remember username and password

Comment: @Vinoth .. what do you want then..?

Comment: i tried but i can get same output. i tried my login page using this link..http://www.anddev.org/simple_login_for_android_g1-t5688.html

Comment: i extra include check box for remember ..please see the link how to implement remember me concept in login page

Answer (score 0):

When the user is unchecking the checkbox, you **should** remove the stored details. Here you are **keeping** the value stored even the user has unchecked the checkbox.

```
 check box
        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    {

editor.putString("username", user);
                    editor.putString("password", pass);
                         editor.putString("checked", "yes");
                         editor.commit();
                    }
                    else
                    {

editor.putString("username", "");
                    editor.putString("password", "");
editor.putString("checked", "no");
                         editor.commit();
                    }
                }
            });
```